# Google maps set limited area with Latitude and Longitude

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, latitude-longitude, google-latitude

I have some problem with google map. I don't know how do that.

I need to set limitation on google maps wit this cordinates

```
Latitude limits
59.132936N <-> 67.600849N

Longitude limits
11.387356E <-> 21.029170E
```

how can i do that?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Firstly convert those coordinates into something that the Maps API can work with.

What you want to then do is create a [LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds) object using those coordinates.

Then call the map's `fitBounds()` method to make the map zoom to those.

And you probably also want to prevent the map being draggable.  Set `draggable:false` in the MapOptions when you construct the map.